# liferay 6.2 integration with two factor authentication

Tags: tomcat, liferay, liferay-6

i m using liferay 6.2 and our requirement is when users try to access our site the page must be redirected to two factor authentication page which is on different server and after successfull authentication user must be able to access liferay site pages.can anybody please help me how to achieve the above requirement.

thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not really clear for me, what you want. Two factor authentication can be done in too many ways. Here on Stackoverflow you need to ask more specific questions.

Comment: hi, my requirement is when user tries to access our Liferay portal they must be redirected to MFA Server and after successfull authentication they must be redirected to Liferay portal's private pages.

Comment: This is still the same unspecific question. We can't help you, if you don't tell us your specific environment, what you have tried so far and where you've got stuck. Read [the help section](/help/on-topic), if you don't understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want a SSO .
You can use [shibboleth](https://www.shibboleth.net) to keep logged between servers.